# Binary Search implementation in Python

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search

I am trying to implement a solution using binary search. I have a list of numbers

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
value to be searched = 2
```

I have written something like this

```
def searchBinary(list, sval):
    low = 0
    high = len(list)

    while low < high:
        mid = low + math.floor((high - low) / 2)

        if list[mid] == sval:
            print("found : ", sval)
        elif l2s[mid] > sval:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1
```

but when I am trying to implement this, I am getting an error like: index out of range. Please help in identifying the issue.

Comment: Why aren't you returning anything? Edit: Nvm, you print it out.

Comment: What's `l2s`? Did you mean `list` there? (Also, never name a variable `list`... it hides the Python built-in `list`.)

Comment: ok, got it. It expects me to return something in case I found the value.

Comment: You seem to interleav `l2s` with `list`...

Answer (score 3):

A few things.

1. Your naming is inconsistent. Also, do not use `list` as a variable name, you're shadowing the global builtin.
2. The stopping condition is `while low <= high`. This is important.
3. You do not break when you find a value. This will result in infinite recursion.

---

```
def searchBinary(l2s, sval): # do not use 'list' as a variable
    low = 0
    high = len(l2s) 

    while low <= high: # this is the main issue. As long as low is not greater than high, the while loop must run
        mid = (high + low) // 2

        if l2s[mid] == sval:
            print("found : ", sval)
            return
        elif l2s[mid] > sval:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1
```

And now,

```
list_ = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
searchBinary(list_, 2)
```

Output:

```
found :  2
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** `high = len(lst) - 1` per comments below.

---

Three issues:

1. You used `l2s` instead of `list` (the actual name of the parameter).
2. Your `while` condition should be `low <= high`, not `low < high`.
3. You should presumably return the index when the value is found, or `None` (or perhaps -1?) if it's not found.

A couple other small changes I made:

- It's a bad idea to hide the built-in `list`. I renamed the parameter to `lst`, which is commonly used in Python in this situation.
- `mid = (low + high) // 2` is a simpler form of finding the midpoint.
- Python convention is to use snake_case, not camelCase, so I renamed the function.

Fixed code:

```
def binary_search(lst, sval):
    low = 0
    high = len(lst) - 1

    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2

        if lst[mid] == sval:
            return mid
        elif lst[mid] > sval:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1

    return None

print(binary_search([1, 2, 3, 4, 6], 2))  # 1
```

Comment: The issue was because I was initialising high = len(lst), but it should be high = len(lst) - 1. And I read that it is good practice to initialise mid = low + (high-low)/2 to prevent overflow.

Comment: You're right that it should be `len(lst) - 1`. `low + (high - low) / 2` is the same as `(low + high) / 2`. I just simplified the expression.

Comment: Yes they are same, but (low + high)/2 can create overflow so that is why it is recommended to use other approach

Comment: You're talking about integer overflow if `low + high` is too large? That seems like a strange concern, and I believe a complete non-issue in Python.

Comment: Yes, suppose high=2^31 and low=1, I try to do (high+low) then it will break the code. This is not related to my issue. I just read it while browsing for the solution.